# Not able to connect to AWS region using boto3

Tags: python, boto3

I am not able to connect to to any region using boto3 i have tried everything using boto3.session.Session, connection = ec2.connect_to_region

connection=ec2.connect_to_region('region_name',aws_access_key_id='',aws_secret_access_key=''

I am getting the below error:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/regions.py", line 135, in _endpoint_for_partition
raise NoRegionError()
botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look like this:

```
import boto
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("us-west-2",
    aws_access_key_id='<aws access key>',
    aws_secret_access_key='<aws secret key>')
```

However, I recommend that you drop using boto and switch to boto3 unless you have a technical reason.

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client(
    'ec2',
    aws_access_key_id='<aws access key>',
    aws_secret_access_key='<aws secret key>',
    region_name="us-west-2"
```